# Combining CommandLine Option Parsers with Scopt

Tags: scala, command-line, scopt

I am currently using `scopt` for a Command Line Application. However My `scopt.OptionParser[Config]` is getting very large. I was thinking it might be nice to break it into smaller parts, and then combine them.

After reading the documentation I don't see any way of doing that.

Did I miss something? Or is it not possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible now. Could you open a GitHub issue for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be broken into smaller chunks.  You can do it by moving functionality into traits something like:

```
trait FooParser { self: OptionParser[MyArgs] =>
  cmd("foo")
  ...
}
trait BarParser { self: OptionParser[MyArgs] =>
  cmd("bar")
  ...
}
val fooBarParser = new OptionParser[MyArgs]("FooBar") with FooParser with BarParser {
  head("FooBar")
  ...
}
```